# How to calculate a line box's height?

Tags: html, css

Below is my test code.

```js
var h_1 = $('.box').eq(0).height();
var h_2 = $('.box').eq(1).height();

$('#txt').html(
  'box#1 height = ' + h_1 + 'px' +
  '<br>' +
  'box#2 height = ' + h_2 + 'px'
);
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box span {
  line-height: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
}

.box span.middle {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.4);
}

#txt {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <span>Blog</span>
  <span>Blog</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <span>Blog</span>
  <span class="middle">Blog</span>
</div>
<br>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

And here is w3.org explains how the line box height calculated:

> 1. The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements, this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'. (See "Calculating heights and margins" and the height of inline boxes in "Leading and half-leading".)
> 2. The inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their 'vertical-align' property. In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom', they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height. If such boxes are tall enough, there are multiple solutions and CSS 2.1 does not define the position of the line box's baseline (i.e., the position of the strut, see below).
> 3. The line box height is the distance between the uppermost box top and the lowermost box bottom. (This includes the strut, as explained under 'line-height' below.)

For the first `<div class="box">`, I think the min-height of it should be `8px` according **rule 1 & 3** above, but the actual height is `6px`, so is there any precision problem and what is the real calculation process behind this?

Comment: Just one thing more: Chrome - 6px, Firefox - 8px. Even IE11 - 8 px. :)

Comment: Thanks, I use safari 10.0.2 on OS X. :)

Comment: hi, Dictator. I also had asked the similar question. I read The Meyer's book (https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=rdtCRLXAL78C&pg=PA519&lpg=PA519&dq=meyer+CSS:+The+Definitive+Guide+css&source=bl&ots=mUZUid3d4u&sig=ncqlrZdFQEvR3u_ofJMkLt2O4N0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUoZmgn_fRAhXI8ywKHUn7B3cQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q&f=false). On the 183rd page there is an explaination, I have read it, but I still do not understand how to calculate a line box's height. Did you find out a good source (article) about the calculation algorithm with examples?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting 9px is because of the following.

```
.box span.middle {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.4);
}
```

I've removed it in the snippet below and works fine at 6px

```js
var i = 0;

$('.box').each(function() {
  i++
  var thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
  $('#txt').append("box #"+i+" height = "+thisHeight+" px<br>");
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box span {
  line-height: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
}

.box span.middle {
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.4);
}

#txt {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <span>Blog</span>
  <span>Blog</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box">
  <span>Blog</span>
  <span class="middle">Blog</span>
</div>
<br>
<div id="txt"></div>
```